# multiple reified parameter types in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

is it possible to have multiple reified type parameters in Kotlin. I can do something like:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> func(column: String): T {
   return when(column) {
      ....
   } 
}
```

Can this be extended to something like:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T, reified U> func(column: String): Pair(T, U) {
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple reified parameters are supported in a regular way. if your problem is that your code does not compile then this is because you wrote `Pair(T, U)` instead of `Pair<T, U>`:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T, reified U> func(column: String): Pair<T, U>
```